# How do I take a screenshot of windows 7 logon screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, login, screenshot

I am trying to create a windows 7 crazy error on scratch but i need a screenshot for my logon screen for the project so can someone tell me how to take a screenshot of my logon screen without any software?

Comment: See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10407/snipping-tool-to-take-a-snapshot-of-login-screen

Comment: If you run the OS in a Virtual machine you can get a screenshot that way.

Comment: Please kindly check if methods in the following link were helpful: [How to Take Screenshots of the Windows Logon Screen](https://www.howtogeek.com/113267/how-to-take-screenshots-of-the-windows-logon-screen-2-geeky-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

Use your Smartphone Camera, make sure lightning is good (no glare), make sure the display is properly framed in the camera, take the picture and send it via Bluetooth.

I have done this successfully numerous times.

You can use a Phone, a Tablet, or even a digital camera.

Comment: ok but i have no phone and i dont have access so I do have an fire tablet with a camera

Comment: So then use the camera on the table to take the picture. It will work the same way. You may need to put the photo on a USB key to transfer it or email it as I noted.

Comment: I have a chromebook to take a picture of it and it has a camera software

Comment: So that should work fine. You can then transfer the picture where you need it

Comment: I am making the project on my chromebook so i found a solution yesterday

Comment: That is good. I think my answer applies so perhaps you could acknowledge it. Thanks.